# How do I solve this NullPointerException Problem?

Tags: java, date, nullpointerexception, return-type

In here, I'm receiving a `NullPointerException` problem which seems to be related to my Date object in my class, but I can't figure it out.
My teacher said that everything works except that I'm returning the wrong data types for my date class, but I KNOW I'm returning a string, after all, that is what a `getDate()` method returns

I've tried putting in the code for the `getDate()` method itself, as in
 `"getMonth() + "/" + getDay() + "/" + getYear();`

```
    //main employee class
public class Employee
{
    //2 attribute for employee
    private String name; 
    private Date dateHired;

    public boolean employeeType; //to check what type of employee, if 
    //false, then employee is salaried, otherwise hourly

    //setter methods
    public void setDateHired(int m, int d, int y)
    {
        Date dateHired = new Date(m,d,y);
    }

    public void setName(String s)
    {
        name = s;
    }

    public void setHoursWorked(int w)
    {

    }

    //getter methods
    protected String getDateHired()
    {
        return dateHired.getDate();
    }
```

There isn't supposed to be an error, I reviewed this code hundreds of times and everything seems to be fine!

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but the `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated and despite its name doesn't represent a date. I recommend that instead you use the modern `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void setDateHired(int m, int d, int y)
{
    //dateHired is a local variable.. you're not modifying the class instance variable.
    Date dateHired = new Date(m,d,y);
}
```

should be:

```
public void setDateHired(int m, int d, int y)
{
    this.dateHired = new Date(m,d,y);
    //or: 
    //dateHired = new Date(m,d,y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before turning to your actual questions, you have

```
private Date dateHired;
```

I recommend you don’t use the `Date` class. It was always poorly designed and is now long outdated. Despite its name it also doesn’t represent a date, but a moment in time at which there are two or three different dates around the globe. Instead use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Use the tutorial link at the bottom.

For the `NullPointerException` Brandon has already explained how that came about from the following line:

```
    Date dateHired = new Date(m,d,y);
```

Using `LocalDate` the line should be:

```
    dateHired = LocalDate.of(y, m, d);
```

In `new Date(m,d,y)` you have got the arguments in the wrong order, you are treating year and month incorrectly and you are using a constructor that has been deprecated for decades, never ever do that.

> My teacher said that everything works except that I'm returning the
>   wrong data types for my date class, but I KNOW I'm returning a string,
>   after all, that is what a getDate() method returns

The `getDate` method has been deprecated just as long, don’t use that one either. It also doesn’t give you the full date, and your teacher is correct, it doesn’t return a string, it returns an `int`.

> I've tried putting in the code for the getDate() method itself, as in
>   `getMonth() + "/" + getDay() + "/" + getYear();`

You’d be surprised. However, rather than getting surprised and confused use a formatter for formatting your `LocalDate` into a string.

```
protected String getDateHired()
{
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT);
    return dateHired.format(dateFormatter);
}
```

Example output from this method assuming US locale and a hire date of December 1, 2018:

> 12/1/18

`ofLocalizedDate` gives you a formatter for the default locale, so if your locale differs from US, you may be pleasantly surprised that the format of the string matches your expectations better than the quoted example. Normally one would declare the formatter a constant (a `static final` variable in the class), but I wasn’t sure that you had learned about this yet, so in this case I didn’t.

**Long story short:** Using the outdated `Date` class correctly is a lot harder than you would think because of its poor design. Don’t struggle with that one. Use of the modern `LocalDate` comes a lot more naturally. It numbers years and months the same way as humans do (at least since year 1 AD) and its method names are clearer, just mention a few of the many advantages.

**Tutorial link**: [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.